# Como normalizar varias imagens em matlab

Tags: matlab, processamento-de-imagens, normalização

tenho um conjunto de 1000 imagens geradas randomicamente atraves do ruido gaussiano, como que eu faria para normaliza-las (mesmo desvio padrao e mesma media para todas a imagens).

OBRIGADO!!